# Cut the length of json data field being displayed

Tags: json

$('#wrapone').append(JSON.stringify(data.GetSource[0]["Person"][0].Name));

How to remove the last 3 characters for data.GetSource[0]["Person"][0].Name before appending it to the div element called wrapone.

Comment: What do you mean by "*remove the last 3 characters*". Please provide more clarity, with example.

Comment: "abcd[1]" -> "abcd"    [hagrawal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4691279/hagrawal)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`var st = JSON.stringify(data.GetSource[0]["Person"][0].Name);`

Then use the substring method:

`$('#wrapone').append(st.substring(0, st.length - 3));`

Comment: [BlackRainz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3376059/blackrainz) - It doesn't work.

Comment: Try debugging it and see what `st` contains before the append, does it contain the value you want?